# Where can I find Iron, Gold, and Diamond in survival mode?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Where can I find Iron, Gold, and Diamond in Minecraft Pocket Edition Survival Mode? I can only find gravel, dirt, wood, sand, and cobblestone.

Answer (score 8):

All of the following information applies to both pocket edition and standard minecraft.

The minecraft wiki has an indepth explanation on [where to find each mineral](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ore). Your issue is most likely that you have not dug deep enough. As you can see from the graph you need to be less than 60 blocks above the bottom of the map to find ores, and rarer ores are deeper.

[image: Percent of ore blocks by height above bedrock]

Answer (score 2):

You have to be below sea level to find iron, below level 32 to find gold, and below level 16 to find diamond.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion is to search for a cave or a ravine. There’s a much higher chance for iron to be there. Dig deeper, and you might find lava lakes. That’s where diamonds have a super high chance of spawning there. Gold? Just go into the nether and find some gold nuggets. Nine of those can be crafted into a golden ingot. If you can’t find a cave, my other suggestion is to strip mine at Y level 10. It’s a super efficient way to get ores like iron and diamonds.