# Can I farm iron in Minecraft Bedrock edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there any decent<sup>1</sup> way to farm iron in Minecraft Bedrock edition (survival mode)?

The best I've found so far is [this silentwisperer's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoYXfnkfg08) based on Pekoneko's iron golem farm. But despite it being designed specifically for Bedrock edition, it seems to have some reliability issues, according to people's comments. I'm willing to spend the week it would take me to build it, but not if it's going to need repairing every time I log in the game.

Laking of another solution, I'm just mining the iron, which is painfully slow. I'm aware of [these tips](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20841/how-can-i-easily-get-a-lot-of-iron) and of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126574/where-can-i-find-iron-gold-and-diamond-in-survival-mode), both helpful when you need a lot of iron... but not so much when you need *an insane amount* of it<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>(1): by *decent*, I mean automatic (or at least semiautomatic) and reliable. It doesn't need to yield a trillion ingots per hour, as long as it isn't slower than actually mining the iron, it's fine.</sup>

<sup>(2): I'm building a rather large auto-organizer storage system, and it will require **10.505** iron ingots for the hoppers alone. I'm already halfway there, but it's taking forever.</sup>

Comment: Not an answer, but I've built [another of silentwisperer's iron farm designs](https://youtu.be/P2Fm9Np0zgk), and it seems to at least function in Bedrock Edition, albeit with pretty marginal return rates. I didn't want to do that build b/c of all the "finding the village leader" stuff. I'm not sure the time investment is worth the return you get, but I haven't actually done a lot of AFK time around that farm. For the trading hall bit, I'm currently in the process of building [Avomance's design](https://youtu.be/RCqNZOGiG_A), but having some issues with my villagers claiming job blocks.

Answer (score 3):

With the latest updates,  Silent's new quad farm is crazy good for bedrock.

Also, you may want to consider building it near your worldspawn so it is active even when you are not in those chunks. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, Elliott. Yes, since the 1.16 update we finally have reliable iron farms. I built another of Silent's designs... not the quad one, but it still produces more iron than I'll probably ever need :)

Answer (score 1):

Make an Iron Golem farm. Sure, it might take a while to build, but it’s totally worth it. You get infinite amount of iron! You can just go afk, sit back and relax instead of searching and mining iron all day long. If you don’t know how to build an Iron Golem farm, you can search it up on YouTube. There’s plenty of tutorials on how to make an Iron Golem farm. There shouldn’t be any problems with your farm afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a zombie farm as zombies have a chance to drop iron on death...

Comment: -1 There are better solutions as anwsers from other people

Comment: Very unlikely, and not worth it. An iron golem farm is much better than hunting zombies down.

Comment: This farm is for *Bedrock Edition*. Adding zombie fear on villagers only works on the Java Edition.